# How to inject async-scoped dependencies into IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, simple-injector

I've implemented `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` in a WebApi2 project. I am using SimpleInjector and have registered services, repositories, etc. with `AsyncScopedLifecycle`. I am injecting these dependencies into my implementation as factories. However, it seems that the OAuth process is not running within an async scope, since I get the following error when trying to authenticate.

> The AdminUserAuthenticationStrategy is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.

My `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` is registered as a singleton, here's the relevant parts of the DI config (note that `AsyncScopedLifecycle` is the default):

```cs
166    container.Register<IAuthenticationStrategy>(() => { ... });
...
226    container.RegisterSingleton<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>(() => {
227        Func<IEnumerable<IAuthenticationStrategy>> authenticationStrategiesFactory = () => new IAuthenticationStrategy[] {
228            container.GetInstance<AdminUserAuthenticationStrategy>(), ...
229        };
230        Func<IEnumerable<ITenantDetectionStrategy>> tenantHostDetectionStrategiesFactory = () => new ITenantDetectionStrategy[] {
231            ...
232        };
...
236        return new AuthorizationServerProvider(authenticationStrategiesFactory, tenantHostDetectionStrategiesFactory);
237    });
```

And here's the injected constructor:

```cs
public AuthorizationServerProvider(
    Func<IEnumerable<IAuthenticationStrategy>> authenticationStrategiesFactory,
    Func<IEnumerable<ITenantDetectionStrategy>> tenantHostDetectionStrategiesFactory) {

    if (authenticationStrategiesFactory == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authenticationStrategiesFactory));
    if (tenantHostDetectionStrategiesFactory == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tenantHostDetectionStrategiesFactory));

    _authenticationStrategiesFactory = authenticationStrategiesFactory;
    _tenantHostDetectionStrategiesFactory = tenantHostDetectionStrategiesFactory;
}
```

When I attempt to "execute" the factory, e.g. `var authenticationStrategies = _authenticationStrategiesFactory();`.

> SimpleInjector.ActivationException occurred   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=The registered delegate for type
>   AdminUserAuthenticationStrategy threw an exception. The
>   AdminUserAuthenticationStrategy is registered as 'Async Scoped'
>   lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an
>   active (Async Scoped) scope.   Source=SimpleInjector   StackTrace:
>   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceTService    at
>   MyProject.Api.Web.Startup.DependencyInjectionConfig.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__9()
>   in
>   C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Api.Web\Startup\DependencyInjectionConfig.cs:line
>   227
>
> Inner Exception 1: ActivationException: The
>   AdminUserAuthenticationStrategy is registered as 'Async Scoped'
>   lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an
>   active (Async Scoped) scope.

**OAuthConfig**

```cs
public static class OAuthConfig {
    public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config, IAppBuilder app) {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Auth/Token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
            Provider = config.DependencyResolver.GetService<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

How can I get OAuth to run within the proper scope?

Comment: Can you provide more context to your question? When do you get this exception and can you post the complete stack trace of the exception and all its inner exceptions.

Comment: @Steven Updated w/exception details and DI config.

Comment: I miss part of the stack trace. Who is calling `AuthorizationServerProvider`. It's important to see the strack trace from all the way up the call graph starting at the incoming request.

Comment: That's the entire stacktrace. ASP.NET is calling `AuthorizationServerProvider`. :-) Via the config I'm adding above, now...

Comment: If this is all the stack trace you see, you are probably running inside the debugger and have breaked on the first chance exception. Let it blow up and take a look at the full stack trace, either by viewing it in the browser or by logging it to disk.